# Successfully access MySQL database from python using optuna

Tags: python, mysql

Since the `optuna` documentation does not address which modules are required from MySQL, I installed everything of MySQL on my Windows 10 machine. I looked for MySQL on my PC (in which folder the installation takes place is not revealed during installation) and updated the Path variables to

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

I have successfully created the `mysqltestexample` database.

[image]

Using python SQL connectors, I can reproduce the output using:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="Start123"
)

print(mydb)


mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for x in mycursor:
  print(x) 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="Start123",
  database="mysqltesteexample"
)
```

Connection to the `mysqltesteexample` does not raise an error - so everything seems to be fine. However, `optuna` is not able to connect to my database

My python script looks like this. It is the code from the `optuna` documentation, I just altered the name of the test database.

```
study0 = optuna.create_study(storage="mysql://root@localhost/mysqltesteexample",study_name="distributed-example")
study0 = optuna.create_study(storage="mysql+pymysql://root:Start123@localhost:3306/mysqltesteexample",study_name="distributed-example")
```

All attempts to modify the URL string according to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html failed with the following error: `ImportError: Failed to import DB access module for the specified storage URL. Please install appropriate one.`
Can you please help me to get it done? Thank you in advance, please don't be too harsh.

Comment: I dont know optuna, so i can not help you to install the optuna-mysql library. But I can help you with the CLI. When you got `mysql>` then you dont need `\!` nor `mysql -u root -p` You can just enter the SQL command: for example `SHOW DATABASES;` or `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;` or any other mysql command.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use all of them. You can see it at the top of my picture. SHOW DATABASES is unknown. Without \! the command gets never executed and without mysql prefix each command is unknown. Without -u and -p the access is denied (see picture).

Comment: I think with the `\!` you'll start a unix-shell on the server... But you need a semicolon `;` in the end of your caomand so it executes.

Comment: You are right. Now I can see the light grey semicolon in the documentation. At least the MySQL commands become less cumbersome. Also -p and -u I actually don't need anymore. Ty

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I made it. I have to install some further packages from the cmd:

```
py -3.8 -m easy_install mysql-python
py -3.8 -m pip install mysqlclient
```

Python packages - as well documented as they are *eyes rolling*

Comment: the mysqlclient package is enough. You don't need the first one for optuna. At least it worked without it for me.

Comment: I concur. `mysqlclient` package is enough